# Setup:upgrade doesn't work

Tags: magento2, setup

I copied my website from localhost to server. For the first 3 days shop worked properly, but now there is an error.

http://demo2.ninethemes.net/fastor/magento2/

Please upgrade your database: Run `"bin/magento setup:upgrade`" from the Magento root directory.

I did it and still, I am getting this error. On localhost, shop works properly. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: after upgrade do php -f bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: I did it and not help.

Comment: refer this link https://magentoexplorer.com/please-upgrade-your-database-run-binmagento-setupupgrade-from-the-magento-root-directory

Comment: Which modules have to delete?

Comment: your outdated modules which is showing http://demo2.ninethemes.net/fastor/magento2/

Comment: I did it. I can pay you $25/h for fix this error. Are you interested?

Comment: I am not freelancer. just i am contributing in stack exchange. I will be availabe in stackexchange chat you can share your details

Comment: Do you have skype? I did everything from article magentoexplorer.com and now there are less errors, but still shop doesn't work. Just check demo.

Comment: we will do step by step. What is the data version and schema version of Magento_Theme module?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this command from the root directory:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

after upgrade you can flush the cache:

```
php -f bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Done. http://files.tinypic.pl/i/00919/d16gt0y2rmxg.png but still the same error

Comment: Have you upgraded your Magento's version?

Comment: Not. Just copied shop from localhost to server. On localhost works properly.

Comment: Have you tried to run **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

Comment: Have  you tried  remove pub/static adminhtml, _cache,_requirejs,frontend, and var/cache page_cache, view_preprocessed, composer_home,generation,di, and the go for  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and flush the cache and give the permissions

Comment: Hi @Artur, I can help you. You can get contact details from my profile.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a new installation or setting up and existing project it is possible that app/etc/config.php file is missing make sure you have env.php already available. To make config.php run the command  bin/magento module:enable --all then run the setup:upgrade and it will work